# How do I make exponents not show leading zeros in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, scientific-notation

When I display numbers as strings in scientific notation using tostring("E4"), the leading zeros are displayed so that the exponent is always three digits. How can I get rid of these leading zeros?

For example, I want this: "5.5E9", and not this: "5.5E+009".

Comment: @MillerKoijam this will replace *all* zeroes on the number

Comment: may need to split by + before that

Comment: that still wouldn't really help because it would still replace any zeros in the exponent. So 5.5E10 would become 5.5E1, which is wrong, won't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Custom Format string:

```
314159.ToString("#.###+E0")
```

Produces

```
3.142+E5
```